# In heredoc what is the delimiter for a single quote

Tags: bash, posix, heredoc

Hello i'm programming a bash posix shell in c and i find this case where i didn't find the correct delimiter for the here doc.

```bash
bash --posix
cat << '
> '  <--- do not work
> \' <--- do not work
```

I would like to know what is the correct behavior in this specific case and where i can found more information about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to use a here document:

> **Here Documents:**
> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the current source until a line containing only a delimiter (with no trailing blanks) is seen.  All of the lines read up to that point are then used as the standard input (or file  descriptor  n  if  n  is
> specified) for a command.
>
> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
> [n]<<[-]word
>   here-document
> delimiter
> ```
>
> No parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, or pathname expansion is performed on `word`.  **If any part of `word` is quoted**, the `delimiter` is the result of quote removal on `word`, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded.  If `word` is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the character sequence <newline> is ignored, and \ must be used to quote the characters , $, and `.
>
> If the redirection operator is `<<-`, then all leading tab characters are stripped from input lines and the line containing the delimiter.  This allows here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a natural fashion.

As stated, If any part of `word` is quoted, the `delimiter` is the result of quote removal on `word`.

The manual of bash also defines what a word is:

> - **`word`:** A sequence of characters treated as a unit by the shell. Words may not include unquoted metacharacters.
> - **`metacharacter`:** A character that, when unquoted, separates words. A metacharacter is a space, tab, newline, or one of the following characters: ‘|’, ‘&’, ‘;’, ‘(’, ‘)’, ‘<’, or ‘>’.

This sort of implies that you can't use a single quote as `word`. I suggest using a real `word` that contains normal letters.

```
cat -- <<'EOF'
   here-doc
EOF
```

**References:**

- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html

Comment: Thanks! The last part of your answer help me a lot to understand how a bash posix should work

Answer (score 3):

The single quote itself is not the delimiter. You started a single-quoted string. If you *want*, for some reason, to use a single quote as the delimiter, you need to escape *it*.

```
$ cat << \'
> foo
> bar
'
foo
bar
$
```

The closing `'` doesn't need to be escaped, because the shell is already looking for a literal `'` to start the line, rather than applying quote removal as usual.

The *opening* delimiter is subject to quote removal because a quoted delimiter behaves differently than an unquoted delimiter. Quoting any part of the opening delimiter causes the entire here document to behave like a single-quoted string, rather than a double-quote string. Observe:

```
$ cat << EOF
> $RANDOM
> EOF
5387
$ cat << 'EOF'
> $RANDOM
> EOF
$RANDOM
```

Comment: It totally make sense